# Change function variable onclick and get it back on the same click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables, totem

I am using this jQuery totem plugin https://github.com/buildinternet/totem

My code:

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('#newslistul').totemticker({
                row_height  :   '34px',
                max_items   :   1
                });
        });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<!-- Start News Bar --> 
    <section id="news">
        <div class="container">
            <p>EV.news</p>
            <div id="newslist">
                <ul id="newslistul">
                    <li><a href="#" title=""><i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-lg" style="margin-right: 4px;"></i> May 25, 2010  Cras sodales augue a nulla tincidunt tincidu sce congue massa enim consequt nonummy</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title=""><i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-lg" style="margin-right: 4px;"></i> Apr 25, 2010  Vivamus sollicitudin erat ut turpis convallis eleife</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title=""><i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-lg" style="margin-right: 4px;"></i> Sept 25, 2010  Cras sodales augue a nulla tincidunt tincidu sce congue massa enim consequt nonummy</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title=""><i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-lg" style="margin-right: 4px;"></i> Sept 25, 2010  Headline lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elitc  vamus id mauris eu mi rutrum tempus</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /.newslist -->
            <a href="#" id="news"><i class="fa fa-plus-square" style="position: relative; top: -8px; color: grey;"></i></a>
        </div><!-- /.container -->
    </section>
    <!-- End News Bar -->
```

I want next:
When you click on

```
<a href="#" id="news"><i class="fa fa-plus-square" style="position: relative; top: -8px; color: grey;"></i></a>
```

link, ul list to expand and show all 4 li.
Variables `row_height: '34px'`, and `max_items:1` should change values to  `row_height : '130px'`, and `max_items: 4` on click on link a href adn get back to 1 on the same click.

Comment: Here is live preview http://promo-moments.com/ev/
It is on top. EV news element.

Answer (score 0):

Write an onClick handler for #news modify $.omr.totemticker.defaultOptions object with new max_items and row_height variable.  $.omr.totemticker is returned by the library when initializing it.
That should help you.

Comment: Ok. Thank you.
First to add onclick="" in #news a.
But how to write this script code?

Comment: This way : $( "#target" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});

Comment: I write this:
$( "#news" ).click(function() { 
                $.omr.totemticker.defaultOptions({
                    row_height  :   '134px',
                    max_items   :   4
                });
            }); 
What to enter in onclick="" in #news a?

Comment: If you read basic jquery you will get it, you dont need to write anything there, just the above code in <script> tags would register the onClick event

Comment: I understand. Got it.
Answer: $( "#news" ).click(function() { 
                $('#newslistul').totemticker({
                    row_height  :   '34px',
                    max_items   :   4
                    });
            });
Thank you.

Comment: What is the oposite of .clickfunction()?
How can I close list on click the same #news a link?

Comment: How I can make this list to close on same click? Thank you.

Comment: One thing you can do is  maintain a flag as a state of  list , toggle each time one clicks on that or you can add a class to the div that will represent the state the list is in, toggle the class on each click.